# FL Studio: Launchkey Mini notes stick

Tags: midi, keyboard, fl-studio

I've just obtained 2 launchkey minis and have been testing them out. I have one on port 165 and the other on port 166. Each is controlling a patcher with the input at each port so that one keyboard controls each patcher. There's nothing complex in each patcher.

The signals route through fine; when a note is pressed, there is a note on message and vice versa for both.

The problem is that, occasionally, a note will stick even if FL registers the note off message. This note stays at exactly the same volume and pitch but will change volume to the velocity of any further presses upon their release.

What is the explanation? And how can it be fixed?

Request further information before down-voting the nonsense out of it please.

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen with both of the launchkey minis or just one of them?

Comment: This happens with both of them. They are on different ports. Interestingly, this only happens when I'm taking an input from the specific port to the patcher, not when just using the "Notes" input.

Comment: What do you mean by "patcher"

Comment: The Image-Line Plugin "Patcher" is a modular-esque plugin that fits into either instrument or effects slots and can be used to link together multiple synths and effects for advanced sound design.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no experience wirhwith FL Studio's Patcher plugin.  Hope you figure out!